# in a key value array, how to increment array value in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array

```
        $rel = array('grandfather' => 0 ,
                    'grandmother' => 0 ,
                    'father' => 0 ,
                    'sister' => 0 ,
            );
```

I want it to compare to the array $family from

```
    $data['family'] = $facebook->api('/me/family?fields=name,relationship,education,location,cover');
```

using the foreach loop

```
     foreach ($family as $families) {

            foreach ($families as $fams) {

                $id = $fams['id'];  
                $name = $fams['name'];

                $relationship = $fams['relationship'];

                foreach($rel as $k => $val){

                    if($k == $relationship)
                    {
                        $val += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

i want the `$val` to increment in each iteration such that if I have 5 sisters.. when i will

```
print_r($rel);
```

the result would be

```
Array ( [grandfather] => 0 [grandmother] => 0 [father] => 0 [sister] => 5 )
```

i have tried the above code but it still returns to 0..

Comment: `foreach($rel as $k => $val)` in here, $k is the index; if the index of the array is numbered (instead of text: `$array(0 => "value")` instead of `$array("txt" => "value");`) the $k will represent a number.    
Otherwise you could always attach a `$inc=0` before the foreach and then `$inc++` within the foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
if($k == $relationship)
{
   $rel[$k] += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work.

foreach ($family as $families) {

```
        foreach ($families as $fams) {

            $id = $fams['id'];  
            $name = $fams['name'];

            $relationship = $fams['relationship'];

            foreach($rel as $k => $val){

                if($k == $relationship)
                {
                    $rel[$relationship]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```